# why is pythono3 panda last udate not working?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

python3.9.x
python3

```
Python 3.9.2 (default, Mar 12 2021, 04:06:34) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import (
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas.util.version import Version
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.util._decorators import (  # noqa
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.properties import cache_readonly  # noqa
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
  File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 48 from C header, got 40 from PyObject
the when I update numpy it said that it needs verson 3.9 ++
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Python version you are using pandas is officially not supported. I would advise to uninstall 3.9 and install 3.7.

Before update or installing the new packages/libraries, always make sure that it is compatible with whatever version you are using.

Comment: Why should we have to go back because pandas can't fix problems?